# Proof of Existence of Von Neumann Numerals in ZFC

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory

Let us recall the recursive definition of the Von Neumann representation of the natural numbers:
$0=\emptyset, S(n)=n \cup \{n\}$

We know by the **Axiom of Empty Set** that $0$ exists, and we are now left with proving whether or not $1, 2, 3$ and so on exist.

$S(n)$ is defined as the Union of the two sets $n$ and $\{n\}$, thus we need to construct the set $X = \{n,\{n\}\}$ and then apply the **Axiom of Union** to obtain $S(n)$.

But how do we know if $X$ exists? Simply by applying the **Axiom of Pairing** to the sets $n$ and $\{n\}$.

Now here's the part where I am completely stuck, how do I know that given $n$ exists, the set $\{n\}$ exists? I thought of applying the Axiom of Pairing to $\emptyset$ and $n$ giving $\{n, \emptyset\}$ but that doesn't go anywhere. Seems incredibly simple and intuitive, but I don't see how this follows from any of the Axioms of ZFC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show me where it says that the axiom of pairing can only be applied to two distinct sets.

It should perhaps be mentioned that you can get the singleton from power set and separation. Which is not a bad idea, since both empty set and pairing are redundant axioms in ZFC.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where the confusion is coming from.
We know $0:=\emptyset$.

We know that we can define $1:=S(0) = 0 \cup \{ 0\} = \emptyset\cup\{0\} = \{0\}$

We know that we can define $2:=S(1) = 1 \cup \{ 1\} = \{0\}\cup\{1\} = \{0,1\}$

And it progresses like this. $n+1:=S(n) = n\cup \{n\} = \{1,\ldots,n-1\}\cup \{n\} = \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$

Of course, $2$ can be written $\{0,1\}$ or it can be written $\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$, if you prefer. We may write $3$ as $\{0,1,2\}$ or as $\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\}$

Im confused by your question because I dont see how any of this is forbidden by ZFC axioms.  We've started with the existence of the empty set and everything has been built from there... using the property of pairing and the rather arbitrary definition of the successor function.